# Twitter date format to Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm retrieving tweets trhough the Twitter Search API and keeping them in MySql database. The problem is this server hasn't installed the PHP DateTime y DateTimeZone libraries (or so I was told) so this method does not work:

```
$datetime = new DateTime($tw_result["created_at"]);
$datetime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($DATETIME_ZONE));
$fecha_tweet = $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

So, do you know other straight way to parse this *"Wed, 08 Feb 2012 23:59:50 +0000"* into *2012-02-08 23:59:50* or a valid date for MySql? (other than slicing with *substrings'*). I tryed several ways of using gmdate() but didn't get to it.

Thank you

Comment: From the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.installation.php) "There is no installation needed to use these functions; they are part of the PHP core."

Comment: @Mike: most likely OP just has php < 5.2

Comment: If your host is using anything < 5.2 I would recommend switching hosts. Even 5.2 support [ended almost 2 years ago](http://php.net/archive/2010.php).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('Wed, 08 Feb 2012 23:59:50 +0000'));
```

http://ideone.com/nFhT6

Answer (score 0):

Twitter created_at to MySql datetime query example.

This query works for me. First split the twitter date format in to strings then concatenate and convert to datetime all in MySql:

```
    SELECT 
    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(dt, ' ', 3), ' ', - 1),
                    '/',
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(dt, ' ', 2), ' ', - 1),
                    '/',
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(dt, ' ', 6), ' ', - 1),
                    ' ',
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(dt, ' ', 4), ' ', - 1)),
            '%e/%b/%Y %r') dtm
FROM
    tweets;
```